# Getting 'ImportError: No module named tornado.httpserver'

Tags: python, tornado, supervisord

Trying to deploy a simple tornado app on my Debian 6 server. I've installed tornado using pip and now it is on:

/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/tornado

Also I added manually the path to tornado on .bashrc of myuser who executes myapp.py:

```
PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/tornado:/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/tornado:/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages
```

myuser is member of www-data group.

I get this annoying error in /var/log/tornado.log:

```
File "/path/to/myapp.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tornado.httpserver, tornado.ioloop, tornado.options, tornado.web, os.path, random, string
ImportError: No module named tornado.httpserver
```

The supervisor.conf is like this:

```
[group:tornadoes]
programs=tornado-8000,tornado-8001,tornado-8002,tornado-8003


[program:tornado-8000]
command=python /path/to/myapp.py --port=8000
directory=/path/to
user=www-data
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/log/tornado.log
loglevel=info
[program:tornado-8001]
command=python /path/to/myapp.py --port=8001
directory=/path/to
user=www-data
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/log/tornado.log
loglevel=info
[program:tornado-8002]
command=python /path/to/myapp.py --port=8002
directory=/path/to
user=www-data
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/log/tornado.log
loglevel=info
[program:tornado-8003]
command=python /path/to/myapp.py --port=8003
directory=/path/to
user=www-data
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/log/tornado.log
loglevel=info
```

Ironically the very same app with the same configs (aprat form /path/to/myapp.py and file owner) was deployed fine on another Debian test server. Really got confused and appreciate your hints.

Comment: Why don't you use virtualenv for installing tornado properly?

Comment: Setting PYTHONPATH manually is a sign of broken-by-design.

Comment: Not sure how to do that in virtualenv

Comment: @qliq [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IX-v6yvGYFg) is a very good tutorial

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't add the tornado directory to PYTHONPATH, but the directory that contains it (dist-packages).  I'm not sure how debian sets up its default python path, but directories like dist-packages and site-packages are usually on it by default.  If they're not, you actually need to add them via a sitecustomize.py file (using site.addsitedir()) instead of just modifying the pythonpath for certain features to work (although this doesn't matter for tornado).

.bashrc is not used when running a program under supervisord.  If you need to change the environment, do so with an 'environment' statement in supervisor.conf.